# Auto-fill gmail BCC line based on To field

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, crm, google-gadget

I am trying to augment my CRM that I have. The high level problem is that I've to enter multiple email addresses every time I want to write a message. This becomes a particular problem when replying to a message and forgetting to enter a special BCCed email address. I'd like to not have to remember to do that. I want, when I am using gmail, for an address in the To/CC line to trigger an auto-population of an address in the BCC line.

Here is how I think I would do this now:

My idea is to do, implement a map/dict/whatever by using two columns in a google spreadsheet (sheet) document. (Using the sheet means an easy visualization to my dict and an easy ability to share with permissions etc.)
The first column would be the To/CC email address and the second column would be the auto-populated BCC email address.

Then I'd like to have code run on my computer that allows me to use gmail as you would without having to think about whatever will automatically go into the BCC field. (Bonus points for figuring out a way for me to code something up that allows me to not have to think about this when sending email from the gmail app on my iPhone.)

It may seem from my abstract description that I would need to hire someone to do this but I know I can code this myself. I just need to be pointed to the correct APIs and be notified of any gotchas that I should avoid.

Currently I was going to write a google contextual gadget to handle auto populating the field. Is that the *best* way? Or is a greasemonkey/whatever script better? What is the general approach I should take to tackling the problem?

To fix the phone/other-email-frontend problem would a Google Apps Script that acts like a cron job to check the most recent sent emails and if they don't have the proper bcc then just forward those emails with an appropriate bcc be reasonable?

Basically, am I off base or on track with my solution? If I am on track give me a bit more information on appropriate plan of attack. If I am off base then point me in the right direction.

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Is this a specific problem to "replying" in Gmail? If so, change the title to reflect it.

Comment: See https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bcc-me-for-gmail/hmkichigbnaamgiokhbjkigjlggpeenf

Comment: This is the best answer I have seen so far. (Not exactly what I need but it helps me down the right path.) Make it an answer instead of a comment and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you are going to be able to do this inside of gmail.  You could save a bunch of Drafts with the correct BCC emails, and put the TO: email in the subject line so that you could see who that draft was meant for, then change the subject line.

You could have a dialog box in your spreadsheet that you designed to look like an email compose screen.  That would be the most straight forward approach.  You could have a stand alone App, that had an input screen that was designed to look like an email compose screen.

Basically, you'd need to design your own user interface rather than using gmail.  But the gmail compose window isn't anything very complicated, so if it's just a plain text email, it should be easy enough.

Comment: Wow. That was not the answer I was expecting. I actually find it difficult to believe. (Worse case I am sure a greasemonkey script could do this.) Perhaps I should start with a simpler question that I thought was possible.

Can I key off of an address in the To/Cc field to add an address to the BCC field using some browser-side code?

Here is a link to the API that I was planning on using to create this Google Apps Script: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/

Comment: Here is an example of a greasemonkey script that gets close to what I want: http://jaidev.info/hacks/gmailAutoBcc  However, I wanted to stay within the google ecosystem of code so I was hoping I could just do it via their scripting stuff.

Comment: If you want to use greasemonkey, and that script is close, ask the developer for what you want.  If Google doesn't currently offer what you want, make a feature request.  [Apps Script Issues and Feature Requests](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list)

Answer (score 0):

Your question would be more understandable with a concrete example of the problem (I'm not sure I entirely understand it). But Gmail supports `mailto:` URLs quite well. Perhaps that is the answer to what you want to do.

There are various scripts to help you generate a `mailto:` the way you want, so have a look at something like http://sislands.com/coin70/week6/mailtoCreator.htm

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! The mailto URL is an interesting idea but doesn't solve my current problem. I will keep that mailto creator around for future use though!